# CMake Build Help for `pyembree`

Tags: windows, cmake, scikits, embree

I am looking for help building `pyembree` from source with CMake for Windows. Further details for the history of this question are listed [here on GitHub](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support/issues/468). Windows support for `pyembree` on conda-forge was just removed, so any help that can be provided would be much appreciated!

### Installation Instructions

#### System

*Tested on:*

**OS:** Windows 10 x64 Professional, Build 1909
**Python:** 3.8.10

#### Steps

1. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.X and Windows 10 SDK](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers). These are required for building `cython` code.

> (**NOTE:** *The version of Microsoft Visual Studio is not the same as the version of Microsoft Visual C++. Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019 all have MSVCv14X build tools. At the time of this writing, installing the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools with*
>
> `MSVCv142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools` and
> `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)`
>
> *components will suffice (select the `Desktop development with C++` Workload if installing Visual Studio 2019).*

2. Install [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html) in `C:\\vcpkg` and add the path to your `System Environment Variables`:

```
C:
mkdir vcpkg
cd C:\\vcpkg
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg integrate install
```

3. Install `embree2 64-bit`:

```
vcpkg install embree2:x64-windows
```

> **NOTE:** *To date, pyembree still relies on Embree 2 and has not been updated for Embree 3.*

4. Install [cmake](https://cmake.org/).
5. Create your project folder and initialize a virtual environment with `venv` (Use `Python 3.6 - 3.8`). In this example, `Python 3.8.5 x64-bit` is chosen as it is the Python version used in `Miniconda py38_4.9.2`.
6. Install the following packages:

```
py -m pip install numpy cython cmake ninja scikit-build wheel setuptools pyvista pykdtree
```

7. Add the following [cmake modules](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build/tree/1fb368ce539b33e0203d3c772559cabec7781976/skbuild/resources/cmake) to your system cmake modules folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.21\Modules\`).
8. Navigate to `<virtual environment folder>\Lib\site-packages` and clone the `pyembree` repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/scopatz/pyembree.git
```

9. Change directories into the `pyembree` folder and create the following top-level `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.0)
project(pyembree
    VERSION 0.1.6
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Build type" FORCE)
endif()

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

find_package(PythonExtensions REQUIRED)
find_package(Cython REQUIRED)
find_package(embree 2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

10. Move to the subfolder `pyembree` and create the following sub-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_cython_target(mesh_construction.pyx CXX)
add_cython_target(rtcore_scene.pyx CXX)
add_cython_target(rtcore.pyx CXX)
add_cython_target(triangles.pyx CXX)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${mesh_construction} ${rtcore_scene} ${rtcore} ${triangles})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC "<system python path>/include"
    PUBLIC "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/embree2"
    PUBLIC "<virtual environment folder>/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include"
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC "<system python path>/libs"
    PUBLIC "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib"
    PUBLIC "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin"
    PUBLIC "<virtual environment folder>/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/lib"
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    embree
)

python_extension_module(${PROJECT_NAME})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

replacing `<system python path>` (e.g. `C:/Program Files/Python38`) and `<virtual environment folder>` accordingly.

11. Move back to the top-level `pyembree` folder and create the following `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages
from skbuild import setup

import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize

include_path = [np.get_include()]

ext_modules = cythonize('pyembree/*.pyx', language_level=3, include_path=include_path)
for ext in ext_modules:
    ext.include_dirs = include_path
    ext.libraries = [
        "C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/embree",
        "C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/tbb",
        "C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/tbbmalloc",
        "C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib/tbbmalloc_proxy",
]

setup(
    name="pyembree",
    version='0.1.6',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

12. Add the following line to the top of every `*.pyx` and `*.pxd` file in `pyembree`:

```py
# distutils: language=c++
```

13. Build and install `pyembree` by running the following from the top-level `pyembree` folder:

```
py setup.py build
py setup.py install
```

14. Finally, install `rtree` and `trimesh`:

```
py -m pip install rtree trimesh
```

## Current Challenge

I am stuck at `py setup.py build`.

1. Currently, I need to copy and paste the `embree` headers and libraries (`.lib` and `.dll`) to the source folder (`<virtual environment folder>/Lib/site-packages/pyembree`) and generated build folder (`<virtual environment folder>\Lib\site-packages\pyembree\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-build\pyembree`)

Is there a copy files command I can use in CMake?

2. When running `py setup.py build`, I get `LNK201: unresolved external symbol` linker errors for `__imp_rtcMapBuffer`, `__imp_rtc_NewTriangleMesh`, and `__imp_rtcUnmapBuffer`. I believe `__imp_` is a DLL construct though, which is only available for the C-Language and shared libraries (not static libraries), so I'm a bit confused.

Any help on this error would be appreciated too!

```sh
Creating library _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pyembree\mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pyembree\mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.exp
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcMapBuffer
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcNewTriangleMesh
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcUnmapBuffer
_skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyembree\mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Comment: "Please find complete details here." - No, this doesn't work on Stack Overflow. Here we expect the **question post** to contain the information needed to understand the problem. A link to that information doesn't fulfil the requirement.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That is absolutely silly, but I will comply. Give me a moment to repeat what is already on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is actually not required. For complete instructions, please see my solution on [Install `pyembree` on Windows without Conda #468](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support/issues/468).